# getting error when I try put phonenumber in createsuperuser in users model in django

Tags: authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-users

I am creating a custom User model Because I want to use the **phone number** for verification. But I encountered an error. I also required email and phone number for verification. when I try put **phonenumber in createsuperuser**, I got error: *the value must be integer*. I searched a lot to find similar error cases, but unfortunately I did not succeed. I would appreciate it if anyone who has a similar experience in solving this problem could help.

models.py & admin.py & Error

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, phone_number, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a user with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must ba set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number,
                          username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        if not extra_fields.get('no_password'):
            user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username=None, phone_number=None, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if username is None:
            if email:
                username = email.split('@', 1)[0]
            if phone_number:
                username = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') + str(phone_number)[-7:]
            while User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                username += str(random.randint(10, 99))
        return self._create_user(username, phone_number, email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, phone_number, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, phone_number, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

    def get_by_phone_number(self, phone_number):
        return self.get(**{'phone_number': phone_number})


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=20, unique=True,
                                help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and _ only."),
                                validators=[
                                    validators.RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$',
                                                              _('This value may contain only letters, numbers'
                                                                'and underscore character.'), 'invalid')
                                ],

                                error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username is already exists.'}
                                )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(_('phone number'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True,
                                    validators=[
                                        validators.RegexValidator(
                                            r'^[+]{1}(?:[0-9\\-\\(\\)\\/\\.]\\s?){6, 15}[0-9]{1}$', ('Enter a valid mobile number'))
                                    ],
                                    error_messages={
                                        'unique': _('A user with that phone number is already exists.')
                                    }
                                    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False, help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True, help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active.Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(_('last seen date'), null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'phone_number']






admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .models import User, Province


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal Info'), {'fields': ('first name', 'last name', 'phone number', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important Dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('username', 'phone_number', 'password1', 'password2'),
                }),
    )
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('username_exact',)
    ordering = ('-id',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, may_have_duplicates = super().get_search_results(queryset, request, search_term,)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(phone_number=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, may_have_duplicates


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Province)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)






error

(venv) PS C:\Users\mehdi\PycharmProjects\my_digital_product> python .\manage.py createsuperuser
Username: mehdi
Email address: mehdi@gmail.com
Phone number: 98745621155
Error: “98745621155” value must be an integer.
```

Comment: error

(venv) PS C:\Users\mehdi\PycharmProjects\my_digital_product> python .\manage.py createsuperuser
Username: mehdi
Email address: mehdi@gmail.com
Phone number: 98745621155
Error: “98745621155” value must be an integer.